# CSS3 radio button customization

Tags: html, css

My task is to make a toggle range (ascendent or descendent). First radio selection is **Ascendent** and the second - **Descendent**. I use sprite file for active, hover or selected case.

How can I remove the Input circles?

[image: image here]

If I put for `.sort-toggle input[type="radio"] - display:none;` I can not see the toggle.

```css
.sort-toggle {
    margin: 0 0 0 50px;
}

.sort-toggle label {
    display: none;
}

.sort-toggle input[type="radio"] {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.sort-toggle-up:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;

    background: transparent url("../img/sprite.png") no-repeat;
    background-position: -77px -461px;

    top: -3px;
    left: 0;    
}

.sort-toggle-up:checked:before {
    background-position: -1px -461px;
}

.sort-toggle-up:hover:before {
    background-position: -40px -461px;
}

.sort-toggle-down::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;

    background: transparent url("../img/sprite.png") no-repeat;
    background-position: -77px -429px;

    top: 0;
    left: 0;    
 }

.sort-toggle-down:checked:before {
    background-position: -1px -429px;
}

.sort-toggle-down:hover:before {
    background-position: -40px -429px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sort-toggle">
    <input class="sort-toggle-up" id="sort-up" type="radio" name="radio-sort" checked>
    <label for="sort-up">Сортировка по возрастанию</label>
    <input class="sort-toggle-down" id="sort-down" type="radio" name="radio-sort">
    <label for="sort-down">Сортировка по убыванию</label>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to remove the circles, but to keep the triangles?

Comment: Yes, the triangles are the customization.

Comment: Personally, I would style some labels and hide the radio buttons entirely. It's much more reliable cross-browser.

Comment: `.sort-toggle input[type="radio"] {opacity:0;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Your interest of my problem. At last I finished by my self.

```css
.visually-hidden {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.sort-toggle input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

.sort-toggle label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.sort-toggle input[type="radio"] + label.sort-toggle-up svg,
.sort-toggle input[type="radio"] + label.sort-toggle-down svg {
    width: 11px;
    height: 10px;
    fill: #c5c5c5;
}

.sort-toggle input[type="radio"]:checked + label.sort-toggle-up svg,
.sort-toggle input[type="radio"]:checked + label.sort-toggle-down svg {
    fill: red;
}

.sort-toggle input[type="radio"]:hover + label.sort-toggle-up svg,
.sort-toggle input[type="radio"]:hover + label.sort-toggle-down svg {
    fill: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="sort-toggle">
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" id="sort-up" name="radio-sort">
  <label for="sort-up" class="sort-toggle-up">
    <span class="visually-hidden">Сортировка по возрастанию</span>
    <svg><polygon points="5.5,0 0,10 11,10 " /></svg>
  </label>

  <input type="radio" id="sort-down" name="radio-sort">
  <label for="sort-down" class="sort-toggle-down">
    <span class="visually-hidden">Сортировка по убыванию</span>
    <svg>
       <polyline points="5.5,10 0,0 11,0 " />
    </svg>  
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make necessary changes in the following, replace the background, etc

```css
.sort-toggle {
    margin: 0 0 0 50px;
}

.sort-toggle label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.sort-toggle input[type="radio"] {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.sort-toggle input[type="radio"]:checked + .dummy-radio {
        position: absolute;
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;
    background: red;
    background-position: -77px -461px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 3px;
    z-index: 9; 
}


.sort-toggle-up:checked:before {
    background-position: -1px -461px;
}

.sort-toggle-up:hover:before {
    background-position: -40px -461px;
}


.sort-toggle-down:checked:before {
    background-position: -1px -429px;
}

.sort-toggle-down:hover:before {
    background-position: -40px -429px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sort-toggle">
    
    
    <label for="sort-up">Сортировка по возрастанию
      <input class="sort-toggle-up" id="sort-up" type="radio" name="radio-sort" checked>
      <span class="dummy-radio"></span>
    </label>
    
    <label for="sort-down">Сортировка по убыванию
      <input class="sort-toggle-down" id="sort-down" type="radio" name="radio-sort">
      <span class="dummy-radio"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure is 'visibility' property have such 'none' value.

Answer (score 0):

i would personally suggest to use available custom codes so you have not to spent more time on it.

Here is an example of a form structure:

```
<form class="ac-custom ac-checkbox ac-cross">
    <h2>How do you collaboratively administrate empowered markets via plug-and-play networks?</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><input id="cb1" name="cb1" type="checkbox"><label for="cb1">Efficiently unleash information</label></li>
        <li><input id="cb2" name="cb2" type="checkbox"><label for="cb2">Quickly maximize timely deliverables</label></li>
        <li><input id="cb3" name="cb3" type="checkbox"><label for="cb3">Dramatically maintain solutions</label></li>
        <li><input id="cb4" name="cb4" type="checkbox"><label for="cb4">Completely synergize relationships</label></li>
        <li><input id="cb5" name="cb5" type="checkbox"><label for="cb5">Professionally cultivate customer service</label></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

The core styles for making the input invisible and creating the box out of the pseudo-element is the following:

```
.ac-custom label {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 0 0 0 80px;
    vertical-align: top;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: color 0.3s;
}

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"],
.ac-custom input[type="radio"],
.ac-custom label::before {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -25px;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"],
.ac-custom input[type="radio"] {
    opacity: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 100;
}

.ac-custom label::before {
    content: '';
    border: 4px solid #fff;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label,
.ac-custom input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    color: #fff;
} 

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before,
.ac-custom input[type="radio"]:checked + label::before {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

You can get custom codes from **Source**

https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/10/15/animated-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons-with-svg/